# mootools tool tips not showing for Request.HTML content

Tags: javascript, css, mootools, mootools-events, mootools-more

I'm having some trouble with adding tips to a Request.HTML
function. I have a div which refreshes its content every 30 seconds.
The content returned has a series of divs with the class name
".liveReader".

Here's the JS I have to initiate the content

```
            window.addEvent('domready', initLiveContent);

            function initLiveContent()
            {
                    var tips = new Tips('.liveReader');
                    (function() { refreshPanel() }).periodical(30000);
                    refreshPanel();
            }

            function refreshPanel()
            {
                    var myRequest = new Request.HTML({
                             url: '/inc/liveFeed.aspx',
                             update: $('liveContent'),
                             method: 'get',
                             onComplete: function() {
                                 tips.attach('.liveReader');
                             }
                    });
                    myRequest.send();
            }
```

So the HTML is

```
<div id="liveContent">
    <div id="item1" class="liveReader" title="item 1"><p>Text 1</p></div>
    <div id="item2" class="liveReader" title="item 2"><p>Text 2</p></div>
</div>
```

Yet all I am seeing is the normal tooltip title! any ideas?!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with variable scoping.

Your `onComplete` handler uses a reference to `tips`, while this variable is local to the `initLiveContent` function. Therefore, the `onComplete` call fails.

So, first tip (no pun intended): always start with an actual debugger, and set it to break on all exceptions. Otherwise, since the error ("undefined variable `tips`") is thrown from within a callback, it won't appear in the standard console.

Then, two ways to fix your code:

1. Make `tips` a shared variable. You might for example declare it in a function that would be the second argument to your `window.addEvent` call, and then reference it in both `initLiveContent` and your `onComplete` callback.
2. Much more Mooish  :) 
   Use [Element storage](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element%3astore) to dynamically retrieve your `Tips` instance from your updated container. That is:

   ```
   function initLiveContent()
   {
       var tips = new Tips('.liveReader');
           // … your previous code …
       $('liveContent').store('tip', tips);    
   }

   function refreshPanel()
   {
       var destination = $('liveContent');
       var myRequest = new Request.HTML({
           update: destination,
               // … your previous code …
           onComplete: function() {
               destination.retrieve('tip').attach('.liveReader');
           }
       });
       myRequest.send();
   }
   ```

:)